# How can I arrange the applications on each page of my app drawer?

Tags: applications, launcher, app-drawer

I have recently bought a Samsung ACE S5830 smartphone and downloaded several applications like astrology, live wallpapers, games, and some daily usage applications.

When I open my application drawer, I see all these applications mixed up and are spread across 5 pages. This is very confusing and makes it cumbersome to find an application I want to use.

How can I arrange the applications on each page? For example, I want astrology related applications on page 1 of the applications page, games on page 2 and the default applications (like Internet, calculator, clock, etc) on page 3.

Is this possible? I have tried folder organizers and app organizers from the Android market but none of them meets my requirement.

Answer (score 3):

You can press the Menu button while in the app drawer and change the view type the "Customizable grid".  Then hit Menu again and "Edit" to rearrange the icons.  It won't let you leave empty spots on a page, though.

Probably the best way to do this is simply to drag the icons onto your home screens, and then you can have a home screen for each type of app.  If you don't have enough home screens then there are probably custom launchers where you can set the number of screens.  Another alternative is folders, as you mentioned; I don't see why they wouldn't work.

Comment: Just a note that some 3rd-party launchers allow you to create folders even within the app drawer, which could be closer to what @Indeevar is looking for.