# How can one move the position of the application inside the launcher?

Tags: launcher

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I arrange the applications on each page of my app drawer?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/19333/how-can-i-arrange-the-applications-on-each-page-of-my-app-drawer)

When I click on the launcher icon (shown on the bottom right corner of the LCD screen as illustrated by Picture A), it will display the list of applications which are installed (as shown in Picture B).

However, I notice that when one boots up the phone, some of the applications are shown and later when the SD card is fully mounted, the rest of the applications are then shown inside the launcher.

So, I was wondering if it is possible to move the location of the applications inside the launcher to another page (assume if there are pages for one to move the applications) or other location in the same page.

Please note that I am not referring to the applications shortcuts or creating applications shortcuts onto the screen of Picture A.

**Picture A**

[image: Picture A]

**Picture B**

[image: Picture B]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using TouchWiz.  If so, go to the App Drawer (Picture B).

The directions below will vary slightly based on the version of TouchWiz you are running.

Hit the `Menu` Button, and select `View Type`, then select `Customizable Grid`.

Then, hit the `Menu` button again, and select `Edit`.  In this view, you can move your icons in the App Drawer.

For what it's worth, you can also edit your dock icons.

Comment: Strange, when I hit `Menu`, it only give me the `Edit`. It did not even give me the `View Type` or the `Customizable Grid`. Wonder if there are any good App Drawer that have much advanced features such as grouping them with a header.

Comment: @Jack, if that's the case, step 1 may be complete.  Try hitting `Edit` and see if it lets you move stuff around.

Answer (score 0):

The default launcher does not allow you to move apps to a different page.  You can sort them as The Andro Nerd suggested - Alphabetically, Last Installed First, or First Installed First.

Some launchers will allow you to hide applications though - in case you were trying to hide the crap-ware that the Telecom's install.

[Apex](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.anddoes.launcher&hl=en) is a great launcher and allows for the hiding of individual apps.
[ADWLauncher EX](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.adwfreak.launcher#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDIxMiwib3JnLmFkd2ZyZWFrLmxhdW5jaGVyIl0.) is another good launcher that you might want to check out.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting some great launcher, which I believe that it might juice out more battery.

Answer (score -1):

Apps in the App drawer are sorted either:

- Alphabetically
- Latest installed last
- Latest installed first

As such, there is no way to move apps in the App Drawer, unless you download a custom home screen app that supports it.

Comment: That very much depends on the launcher used. Some of them allow for manual sorting, or even permit creating folders within the drawer.

Comment: He was talking about the stock launcher.